# How to change Background in ggplot (R) by factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the color of the background of my figure by factor (Foodregime), but R is filling my figure always only with the first color (gray100). 
Foodregime contains "ad" and "r". I want to have a different background color for those two.

Here is my code:

first I created a new variable, because I always got the `Error of "invalid color "ad""`.

This was working.

```
data$color <- revalue(data$Foodregime, c("ad" = "gray100", "r" = "gray88"))

ggplot(data, aes(x = Date, y = x,col = Oiltype)) +
geom_point(pch = 1,cex = 0.1) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) + 
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = data$color))
```

Please note that I can`t set the borders by myself because my data frame is very large. So I really need to solve this with the factor.
Every help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. A plot can only have one background color. What part do you want to be `gray100` and what parts do you want to be `gray88`? Can you provide a [mcve] of your problem, including a reproducible data set?

Comment: look up `geom_rect()` or `geom_tile()` [link to docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html). You can't have two different background colors, annotating different colored rectangles onto your plot is the workaround.